# C++ Inclusion guards being "ignored" between projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include, static-libraries

I have two projects; a static library and an executable (standard Win32 setup, using the multithreaded debug dll setting for both).
In my libray, I have a `Globals.h`, with the following code:

```
#ifndef _GLOBALS_H
#define _GLOBALS_H

#include <SDL.h>
#include <string>

namespace Eng
{
    bool Run = true;

    SDL_Window *Window = NULL;
    SDL_GLContext GlContext;

    Uint32 WindowFlags = SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL;
}

#endif
```

This is all fine and dandy, and within that project everything works fine. However, as soon as I include that file within more than one file in my executable project (all protected by inclusion guards), I start getting multiply defined symbol errors for each variable within `Globals.h`.

As well, I'm getting quite a few macro redefinition warnings from `math.h` (`M_PI macro redefinition`). I'm not sure if this is linked, but it seems likely due to the similar nature of error (guards defined in one project seemingly not applying in the other).

Anyone have any ideas how to resolve this? I feel like I'm missing some vitally important compiler setting somewhere :(

Comment: Simple. Don't put definitions into headers. Inclusion guards solve a completely different problem.

Comment: By definitions, do you mean the assignment of the variables? 'cos that just occurred to me :/ If not, how else are you meant to define global variables?

Comment: Declare your variables as `extern` and define them in a `.cpp` file.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. Forgot about that *sigh*

Comment: Don't define them in the header. Only *declare* them.

Comment: Ok, in that case I guess I understand why I was getting macro redefinitions. Is there any way of avoiding those, because they're defined in math.h?

Comment: Typical scenario of assuming "it's the compiler's fault" :/

Comment: No, I assumed it was my fault, and that I didn't know of a necessary switch for the compiler, or had been making a mistake with my code. I had, and I now know what.